# Read csv value in loop controller Jmeter

Tags: loops, csv, jmeter

I have a loop controller in thread groups to read one csv file and i want to read all line in this csv file.
I config my thread group as below:

- Loop Controller (4 times)
- - Read csv file (Recycle on EOF: False, Stop thread on EOF: True, Sharing mode: All threads)

I run this scenario with a number of threads: 2

- With first thread, read the first line of CSV file
- With second thread, read the second line of CSV file

After each loop,  i got data from CSV file is not changed, so how can i read each line of csv (from 3rd line,...) after the loop?

Comment: How are you verifying that jmeter is not picking up the line 3 on the second loop iteration?

Comment: I add Debug Sampler to check value of variable for each loop

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to put [CSV Data Set Config](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config) as a child of [Loop Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Loop_Controller).
It should work for you with CSV Data Set Config settings you specified.
I create Test Plan:

```
    Thread Group
    Number of Threads = 2
        Loop Controller
        Loop Count = 4
            CSV Data Set Config
            Filename: ... (your csv-file here)
            Variable Names: number
            Delimiter: ,
            Recycle on EOF = False
            Stop Thread on EOF = True
            Sharing Mode = All threads
            JSR223 Sampler
            log.info(vars.get("number"));     // output ${number} variable values
```

Each Loop my "CSV Data Set Config" reads line into a "number" variable.
JSR223 Sampler print it's value to Log Viewer.

My CSV file looks like

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

So, because of Recycle on EOF is FALSE, Stop thread on EOF is TRUE the first Thread read 4 lines in the loop and the second Thread read just one the 5th line and then stop.

[See the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jkRCm.png)

Comment: Thanks for detail comment. Let me check again as your pic

Comment: Hi Vadim, your solution is correct. Thanks so much. But in my script, i have one if controller before read csv file, to make sure correct csv data will be read (because i have many data) and i put CSV data config as a child of IF Controller. This thing make this issue, when my script run loop, it go to csv but only read one line as i description. Do you have any idea about this? This is the first time i met this issue

Comment: OK, i fix this issue, because variable read from csv have scope in If controller so we need to put this value to another var and then can use out of if controller